# Pip installation failed: could not fetch URL

Tags: python, pip

I am running `cmd` as administrator and I created a `venv` and a `pip` file. But when trying to `pipenv install zappa`, it says (note: this applies to everything, whether it is `flask` or `libssl-dev` etc.) :

```
Error:  An error occurred while installing zappa!
Error text: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/zappa/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/zappa/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/zappa/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/zappa/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/zappa/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/zappa/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/zappa/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zappa (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for zappa

Installation Failed
```

What is the cause? I tried to install it outside the environment, it does work but then when I run `zappa init` it doesn't recognize Zappa.

I see this is a common question, where it is recommended to upgrade pip (it is upgraded) or install some other libraries such as `libssl-dev`, but this doesn't work either because I can't install anything using pip. I am using Windows.

Comment: @msanford I tried it, this is why I tried to install, for example, libssl-dev (I use Windows). Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please run pip install zappa inside your virutal env & then run zappa init

Comment: I already tried it and I get the same error. If I do it outside the environment it does work, but then init doesn't work :/